# Prove Discounted Gains Vector and Portfolio are Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, stochastic-processes, finance

Let $\overline{S}=\{S^0,S^1,...S^n\}$ be a one-period market model with one riskless asset and $n$ risky assets, where $S_t^i$ denotes the value of asset $i$ at time $t$. Further assume that $\overline{S}$ is nonredundant, i.e. for a portfolio $\overline{\theta} \in \mathbb{R} ^{n+1}$, $\overline{\theta} \cdot\overline{S}=0 $ $\implies$ $\overline{\theta}=0$. Denote $X^i$ as the discounted value of asset $i$, that is, $X_t^i=\frac{S_t^i}{S_t^0}$. Finally, denote $\Delta X_1$ as the discounted gains, i.e. $\Delta X_1 = X_1-X_0$. Prove the following $$\theta \cdot \Delta X_1=0 \implies \theta =0$$

For those of you unfamiliar with the notation, the portfolio vector $\overline{\theta}$ denotes the number of shares of asset $i$ to purchase. Note that $\overline{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ but $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ due to the discounting.

I've tried a few methods but nothing has worked. I tried to express $\Delta X_1^i$ as a linear combination of $\Delta X_1^j$'s but could not figure out how to proceed. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Is $\theta \cdot S = 0 \implies \theta = 0$ possible when $n > 0$? Does there need to be some other constraint on $\theta$, like $\theta^i > 0$ for all $i$ (a "long-only" portfolio)?

Comment: Yes, $n$ must be greater than zero. And no, $\theta^i$ need not be positive, if its negative its equivalent to shorting.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding notation then. If $n > 0$ and $S$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then I can always find another nonzero vector $\theta$ such that the dot product $\theta \cdot S$ is zero. So from the way I’m reading the problem, the nonredundancy condition makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps I should also state that all the $S^i$'s are random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. The non redundancy condition basically states that no asset's payoff can be replicated by a linear combination of the other assets

Answer (score 1):

In some textbooks the riskless asset price is $S^{0}= 1+r$, with $r \geq 0$ and constant, so let´s assume that $S^{0} \not = 0$.

Suppose that $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is such that $\theta \cdot \Delta X_{1} = 0$ then $\theta \cdot X_{1} = \theta \cdot X_{0}$, if $\bar{\theta} = (-\frac{1}{S^{0}}\theta \cdot X_{0} , \theta_{1},...,\theta_{d})$ therefore:

$$\bar{\theta} \cdot \bar{S} = \bar{\theta_{0}}(S^{0}) + \theta \cdot X_{1} = -\theta \cdot X_{0} + \theta \cdot X_{1} = 0 $$

By non-redundancy $\bar{\theta} = 0 $ and in particular $\theta = 0$.